# How to get value of a cell above a table in Excel

Tags: excel, cell, vba

I have a function that loops through all my sheets. Each loop has a loop inside that loops through all tables within the sheet.

I cannot figure out how to get the value of a cell that is directly above the table column headers.

[image: See Image]

```
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ActiveSheet.Name <> sh.Name And Not sh.Name = "Template" Then
        For Each tbl In sh.ListObjects
            I need those values here
        Next tbl
    End If
Next sh
```

Comment: these values are not part of tables that your are looping through

Comment: can i not go something like. tbl.Select.Offset(0,-1).Value
Or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answered your own question (almost):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub tblTitle()

    Dim sh As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ActiveSheet.Name <> sh.Name And Not sh.Name = "Template" Then
            For Each tbl In sh.ListObjects
                With tbl.Range(1, 1)
                    If .Row > 1 Then MsgBox .Offset(-1, 0)
                End With
            Next tbl
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub
```

For the tables in the image bellow it will show 2 messages: "A" and "B"
[image]